# How to close JFrame without closing another

Tags: java, swing

I know this question has been addressed many times, but I tried everything to make it work properly. First and foremost, I create a JDialog as my loading pop-up when the user login is legitimate. Then I create a Timer to automatically dismiss the frame, and my main menu appears. However, my main menu is also shutting. I set the defaultCloseOperation to DO NOTHING ON CLOSE as well.

LoginForm

```
public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginForm
     */
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        password = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Login = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelpassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelusername = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Login.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Login.setText("Login");
        Login.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)));
        Login.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                LoginMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 76, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        labelpassword.setText("Password");

        labelusername.setText("Username");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(143, 143, 143)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 226, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(password))
                            .addComponent(labelpassword)
                            .addComponent(labelusername))))
                .addContainerGap(93, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(labelusername)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(labelpassword)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void LoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
   Loading loading = new Loading(this, true);
   loading.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
   loading.setVisible(true);
    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Login;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelpassword;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelusername;
    private javax.swing.JTextField password;
    private javax.swing.JTextField username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

JDialog as pop-up loading

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
                                                                                                           

public class Loading extends javax.swing.JDialog {
  
    public Loading(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();
     // I tried alrealdy to dispose the Login Form but doesn't working hence I will using this
     LoginForm exit = new LoginForm();
     exit.setVisible(true);
     exit.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(exit, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
     MainMenu menu = MainMenu();
     menu.setVisible(true);
    
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();    
           
        }
    /**
     * 
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        MainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        PleaseFIll = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        MainPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(24, 25, 32));
        MainPanel.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        PleaseFIll.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        PleaseFIll.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        PleaseFIll.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        PleaseFIll.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/restaurantorderingandpayment/images/hourglass.gif"))); // NOI18N
        MainPanel.add(PleaseFIll, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 20, 230, 60));

        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/restaurantorderingandpayment/images/loading.gif"))); // NOI18N
        MainPanel.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 80, 230, 30));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(MainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 232, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(MainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Loading.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Loading dialog = new Loading(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
              
           
                   
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel MainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel PleaseFIll;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

MainMenu

```
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainMenu
     */
    public MainMenu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("WELCOME");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(171, 171, 171)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use more than one frame. 2) As a general tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Create and show the main frame before disposing of the loading dialog. `LoginForm exit = new LoginForm();` seems pointless in the timer

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is a bad idea, learn to make use of the avaliabe layout managers, in fact, ditch the form editor and learn to do this by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
LoginForm exit = new LoginForm();
exit.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(exit, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

makes no sense at all, the instance of `LoginForm` you've created here has nothing to do with the one which was created eailier, in fact, `Loading` has no responsibility for managing it, it's beyong it's scope.

A simple solution would be to make use of an "observer pattern", so that when `Loading` has actually completed, it can inform any intertested parties and they have can take care of what should be done next.

For example...

```
public class Loading extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public interface Observer {
        public void loadingDidComplete();
    }

    private Observer observer;

    public Loading(java.awt.Frame parent, Observer observer) {
        super(parent, true);
        this.observer = observer;
        initComponents();
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                observer.loadingDidComplete();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();

    }
```

And then in your `LoginForm` you could so something like...

```
private void LoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Loading loading = new Loading(this, new Loading.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void loadingDidComplete() {
            dispose();
            JFrame frame = new MainMenu();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    loading.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    loading.setVisible(true);
}
```

Oh, and you really, really need to look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), again, stop using the form editor, it's not doing your any favours

However, oddly enough, since you're using a modal dialog, you could simply do...

```
private void LoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Loading loading = new Loading(this);
    loading.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    loading.setVisible(true);

    dispose();
    JFrame frame = new MainMenu();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and get the same effect

Comment: Sir, thank you for your time! , my issue solve, please excuse me since I'm just learning about java swing and it's vital to do it by hand.

Comment: Hello Sir, How can I close the JDialog that you given by a button?. I already tried dispose();, dispatchEvent, setVisible method and change the modality of the JDialog but won't work any I've mentioned

Comment: You MUST have a reference to the instance of the dialog that is presented on the window

Comment: Do you have any example sir?

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Sir, I have a question when I calling the method from the other class then the dialog from that method doesn't place at the center. Do you have idea sir?